# Machine learning algorithms for time series analysis

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, supervised-learning

I am wondering which ML algoirthms (supervised) are commonly used for TS analysis. 
Which ones have used and found to be succesful for your projects?

Comment: Look into sequence-to-sequence (neural network) models.

Comment: Are you interested in a specific subfield of time series analysis, like forecasting for example?

Comment: Long short term memories may help you

Comment: @Imran indeed I am

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on the task you are looking to accomplish with your time series data. Is it a regression or a classification task. In general, Random Forests are known to be easy to use and pretty useful. So I think it's a good way to start. Of course, dimensionality reduction techniques and feature extractors like PCA, kernel PCA, t-SNE and many others are very useful if you want to get better results. Neural networks are also useful, depending on the task you can try both recurrent (LSTM) or convolutional NN.

Comment: I guess pointing OP to the resources where someone has successfully implemented regression tasks using above techniques seems better. Op can then decide what he/she wants to achieve and what to use.

Comment: what about in the domain of scikit learn? Any techniques that stick out from there which are known ot be useful for time series forecasting?

Comment: There are a lot of linear models. Check out arima and it's variants. They come in statsmodel library. Pyflux is a new library, fairly, that got some time series models implemented.

Comment: regression task @HatemB

Comment: Yes in fact, there are a lot of linear autoregressive you can maybe start with like arima unfortunately I don't think that autoregressive models are implemented within scikit learn but you can easily find libraries that provides them on python or R. There are also many non linear predictors like random forests regressor.